# Azure Data Factory Data Flow source query support for FOR JSON AUTO

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to use below query as source for my data flow but I keep getting errors. Is the fuctionality not supported in data flow?

```
SELECT  customer.customerid  AS 'customerid',
        customer.customer_fname AS 'fname',    
        customer.customer_lname AS 'lname',
        customer.customer_phone AS 'Phone',
        address.customer_addressid as 'addressid',
        address.Address_type as 'addresstype',  
        address.street1  as 'street1'
FROM customer customer  
   INNER JOIN customer_address address
     ON customer.customerid = address.customerid  
order by customer.customerid
FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('customer')
```

I get the following error:

```
Notifications
Column name needs to be specified in the query, set an alias if using a SQL function
```

ADF V2, Data Flows, Source

Comment: what's the source, SQL database? Did you set it in Query option?

Comment: @LeonYue, thank you for replying. The source is SQL database. I set the Query in the 'Source Options' >  'Input' (Query) > Query (text box).

Comment: The error is cause by that Data Flow Query doesn't support `order by` statement, not the 'FOR JOSN AUTO'. Please see my answer. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

The error is cause by that Data Flow Query doesn't support `order by` statement, not the 'FOR JOSN AUTO'.

See the error bellow:
[image]

Please refence Data [Flow Source transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#source-transformation):

**Query:** If you select Query in the input field, enter a SQL query for your source. This setting overrides any table that you've chosen in the dataset. **Order By clauses aren't supported here, but you can set a full SELECT FROM statement.** You can also use user-defined table functions. select * from udfGetData() is a UDF in SQL that returns a table. This query will produce a source table that you can use in your data flow. Using queries is also a great way to reduce rows for testing or for lookups.

```
SQL Example: Select * from MyTable where customerId > 1000 and customerId < 2000
```

The query work well in Copy active but false in Data Flow. You need to change the query.

Comment: How about this error then? Column name needs to be specified in the query, set an alias if using a SQL Function. Removed my ORDER BY but I still use Max(CreatedDate) AS NewDate in my query